# Conditional probability and independence 5

Tags: probability

Hi guys a little help would be appreciated. 
A balanced die is tossed $12$ times. Given that a $3$ occurs at least once, what is the probability that it occurs four times or more?

I tried to calculate but can't seem to get it right.

- $P(3 \text{ occurs at least once})=1-P(3 \text{ doesn't occur})$
- $P(3 \text{ doesn't occur})=\frac{5^{12}}{6^{12}}=0.112$
- $P(3 \text{ occurs at least once})=0.887$
- $P(((3 \cap 3\cap 3)^c)|3 \text{ occurs at least once})= $ and im stuck

Comment: please include your attempt. thanks.

Comment: How did you try to calculate it? What formula do you know for conditional probability?

Comment: P(3 occurs at least once)=1-P(3 doesn't occur)
P(3 doesn't occur)=(5^12)/(6^12)=0.112
P(3 occurs at least once)=0.887
p(((3n3n3)^c)|3 occurs at least once)= 
and im stuck

Comment: What is the chance it occurs four times or more?  (*It might easier to answer instead the probability that it occurs three times or less*).  Remember that the probability of $A$ given $B$ is defined as $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.  What is useful to call event $A$ here?  Event $B$?  What are the corresponding probabilities?

Comment: I can say B=3 occurs at least once and A= 3 occurs 4 times or more. Now trying to calculate them I’ll go with the inclusion exclusion but I didn’t get the final answer as it is 0.141 probably because I said that P(AnB)=P(A).p(B). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Siong stated,

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 4|X \geq 1)&=\frac{P(X \geq 4)}{P(X \geq 1)}\\
&=\frac{1-P(X\leq 3)}{1-P(X=0)}
\end{align}

How do you calculate these?

$$P(X \leq 3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)$$

Using the binomial formula,

$P(X=0)$ $=$$12\choose0$ $\frac{1}{6}^0$ $\frac{5}{6}^{12}$

$P(X=1)$ $=$$12\choose1$ $\frac{1}{6}^1$ $\frac{5}{6}^{11}$

$P(X=2)$ $=$$12\choose2$ $\frac{1}{6}^2$ $\frac{5}{6}^{10}$

$P(X=3)$ $=$$12\choose3$ $\frac{1}{6}^3$ $\frac{5}{6}^{9}$

According to R, this should come out to be $.8748$.

Do the calculations and you should find that

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 4|X \geq 1)&=\frac{P(X \geq 4)}{P(X \geq 1)}\\
&=\frac{1-P(X\leq 3)}{1-P(X=0)}\\
&=\frac{1-.8748}{1-.1122}\\
&=.141
\end{align}

Comment: As for getting better at the material, I would suggest watching videos and reading the text when you learn about a new distribution. There are many. You'll eventually get accustomed to identifying which one is relevant to the problem at hand. The binomial distribution is one of the most important ones.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the number of times $3$ occur.

$$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(12, \frac16)$$

We are interested in:

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 4|X \geq 1)&=\frac{P(X \geq 4)}{P(X \geq 1)}\\
&=\frac{1-P(X\leq 3)}{1-P(X=0)}
\end{align}

You just have to find out what is $P(X \leq 3)$ and $P(X=0)$ to evaluate the expression above.

Comment: Although I do understand this notations but I’ve not been introduced the binomial thing.

Comment: [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) models out of $n$ trials where each trial is independent and has success probability $p$, what is the probability tha there are $x$ success. It has the following pmf, $P(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$.

Comment: yes I see what you mean but the textbook I'm using uses this formula in the next chapter. Is there another way to get around without invoking these formulas ?

Comment: You can derive the formula on your own, one doesn't require a textbook. Consider $P(X=1)$, consider $12$ boxes, how many options are there to place a success among twelve of them and what is the corresponding probability. Do it for $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$ too.

Comment: I tried to go this way still no luck. P(X=1)=(\binom{12}{1})/2^12

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{2^{12}}$?

Comment: I have 12 way to put a success in one of those 12 boxes so its (12C1)/2^12

Comment: I'm really sorry, but this is a subject that I find really hard I'm really trying to master it

Comment: It should be $\binom{12}{1}\frac{1}{6}\left( \frac56\right)^{11}$. Notice that we use $\binom{12}{1}$ to choose the special box, and the corresponding probability for that particular configurration is $\frac{1}{6}\left( \frac56\right)^{11}$. Learning requires patience and making mistakes. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I did understand the whole thing now but how did you know that I was supposed to use the binomial formula ? does it work with all success failure problems ? do you change the problem format to make it work, like changing notation etc.. ? or by doing more exercises I'll understand ?

Comment: Hmm... I understand the definition of binomial distribution. If you have a total of $n$ trials and they have the same probability of success, $p$, and they are independent, if your goal is to count what is the number of success, then it follows a binomial distibution. Notation helps to make things clearer. More exercises might help a bit but I think understanding is more important. Busy doing exercises with no understanding doesn't help. It just makes you ... well... busy.